# Group of script calls for buttons in a .js using wheelzoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 12 buttons each with an ID, i'm using this script for the action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#WEyear18000").click(function() {
    $("#WEtextarea").load("Files/Docs/y18000.txt");
    $('#WEimage_view').html('<img src="Files/Image/treesimages/PalaeoGlaciolMaps.jpg" >');
    $('#WEee244f5837 .PullZone').click();
    wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
  });
});
```

`WEyear18000`, is the id of button, `WEtextarea`, is the id of the div where txt is displayed on button click, `WEimage_view`, is the id of the div where new image displayed on same button click, `WEee24f5837`, is the id to close a collapsible panel where buttons are located.

There are 12 of these script statements in a .js file.

It all works but it causes some strange effects after the 2nd or another button is clicked, all the images on the page disappear but the one on the button click. Page is here, [page with issue](http://clanmaclellanancestry.com/Doggerland_Map.htm)

Any suggestion on how to stream line script wanted. I a newbe to scripting but managed to hodgepodge this to work but has and adverse affect on the rest of the pages images. Suggestion and samples to jsfiddle. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="WEtextarea"> </div>
  <div id="WEimage_view"></div>
</div>
```

CSS controls size and all aspects of div.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all your menu items... And did not notice such a bug.

So, while your're here... I have a suggestion to reduce your long script made of a small chunk repeated 12 times.

I would define the maps as objects, like this:

```
var maps = [
  {
    buttonId: "WEyear18000",
    text: "Files/Docs/y18000.txt",
    image: "Files/Image/treesimages/PalaeoGlaciolMaps.jpg"
  },
  {
    // other 11 objects using the same structure...
  }
];
```

And I would just add a class to each items, in the HTML, like this:

```
<div id="WEyear18000" class="BaseDiv RBoth OEWELinkButton OESK_WELinkButton_Default OECenterAH clickHandlerClass" style="z-index:1">
```

Then, I would use a shorter function like this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".clickHandlerClass").click(function(){

    // Get the id of the clicked menu item
    var thisId = $(this).attr("id");

    // Find its related object
    var mapIndex = -1;
    for(i=0;i<maps.length;i++){
      if( maps[i].buttonId == thisId ){
        mapIndex = i;
      }
    }

    if(mapIndex != -1){
      // Use the object infos in the page elements.
      $("#WEtextarea").load(maps[mapIndex].text);
      $('#WEimage_view').html('<img src="'+maps[mapIndex].image+'" >');
      $('#WEee244f5837 .PullZone').click();
      wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
    }else{
      console.log("Undefined map or id error...");
    }

  });
});
```

The array of objects is way easier to maintain... And an additional button easier to add.
You can use another class name than *"clickHandlerClass"*.
;)

Comment: Would the var array  and the clickHandlerClass all be together in one .js, or would that be to files.

Comment: I put it all together in one file with two other statements and it work great.  I would like to Thank you all for your great assistance, I've been coming to this site for the last year and have learned a lot, but this was the first post asking for help, and, the response was outstanding.

Comment: No problem to place it in the same file. ;) SO is a great site, yes!

Answer (score 1):

The `wheelzoom` looked like the only possible source of error to me. So I looked for its [source](http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/), and found:

> Wheelzoom replaces an img's background-image with its src. Then the src is set to a transparent image.

So, on the first wheelzoom, you get `src` transeparent, and on the second, you get a transparent `background-image` as well.

You can fix this by calling wheelzoom only on your new image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#WEyear18000").click(function() {
    $("#WEtextarea").load("Files/Docs/y18000.txt");
    $('#WEimage_view').html('<img src="Files/Image/treesimages/PalaeoGlaciolMaps.jpg" >');
    $('#WEee244f5837 .PullZone').click();
    //wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
    wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('#WEimage_view img'));
});
```

Comment: wheelzoom  calls a small script that enlarges the image in the div, I tried changing to your suggestion and everything stopped working. Got it from here; http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom

Comment: I'm quite certain that calling wheelzoom twice will blank out your images. The quote in my answer is from their site, and it pretty much guarantees that calling wheelzoom on the same image twice will blank it out. Just to test, try commenting out the call to `wheelzoom` in your function, and see if the images remain on the page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'everything stopped working', but the idea is to only call wheelzoom on the single new image you added, not all images in the document.

Comment: You were right, I commented out the wheelzoom and everything stays put, I then add your  wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('#WEimage_view img')); to the new array script and waalaa that worked, i now see where you were going.

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Maybe I'll add your whole function to my answer so it's clear I mean to make the change just there.

Answer (score 0):

to fix your bug you need to replace:

```
wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
```

with:

```
wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('#WEimage_view img'))
```

So only the images in the #WEimage_view will be affected by wheelzoom